# How to use placeholders with openpyxl?

Tags: python

I figured it out few weeks ago, but forgot how to do it again.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for i in range(20):
    ws['A{i}'] = 'test'

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

How can I replace the i in {i} with the numbers I want to enumerate?

Comment: `ws[f'A{i}'] = 'test'`

Comment: You're trying to use "f-strings" without prepending the string with `f`. It has nothing to do with `openpyxl`, this is fundamental Python syntax